# Remove active class from parent menu link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I have a menu that when you click on a parent menu it shows a sub menu...this is working fine as you can see [here](http://foley13.webfactional.com/sotl). I also have an active class that is controlled by a small jquery script but my issue is that when I click off an active link the active state is stilled being applied. For example if you click Menu Five the arrow toggles and an actve state is applied but when you click the menu again the submenu dissapears yet the active state is still applied.

here is the active state jquery snippet:

```
// create active class when menu is active
    var selector = '.james';

    $(selector).on('click', function(){
        $(selector).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to toggle the `active` class, and you also need to exclude the currently clicked element when removing the class (*so it only applies to the other menu options*)

```
var selector = '.james';
$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```